Is there a way to prevent the constraintrange from snapping in a plotly parcoords with tickvals
I want to create a parcoords-plot with custom axis with tickvals. This is doable, but then the constraintrange does work and only allows to constraint for the tickvals.
From time to time this might be intended behaviour, but in my case it is not. As far as I can see there is no way around, but maybe there is? It is not possible to use an empty label because otherwise the axis is completely destroyed. Here you have an example:

library(plotly)
ticktext <- ifelse(
  ((0:100)) %% 10==0, 
  as.character((0:100)/100),
  "emptyLabel"
)
plot_ly(
  type = "parcoords",
  dimensions = list(
    list(
      label = "a",
      values = runif(100),
      range = c(0,1),
      tickvals = (0:5)/5,
      constraintrange = c(.1, .4),
      ticktext = as.character((0:5)/5)
    ),
    list(
      label = "b",
      values = runif(100),
      range = c(0,1),
      tickvals = (0:100)/100
      #ticktext = as.character((0:5)/5)
    ),
    list(
      values = runif(100),
      range = c(0,1),
      tickvals = (0:100)/100,
      ticktext = ticktext,
      label = "c"
    )
  )
)



As you can see the constrainrange is not not [.1, .4].
This issue has already been mentioned here, but there is no answer: https://community.plotly.com/t/parallel-coordinates-plot-constraint-range-snapping-behavior/39024
See this animation for the snapping behaviour:

Used R- and plotly-version:
R version 4.3.1 (2023-06-16 ucrt)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19045)

other attached packages:
[1] plotly_4.10.4 ggplot2_3.5.1

The following text is irelevant to the question, it is only an explanation why I have to use tickvals:
I absolutely need to use tickvals, because in my usecase there are NA in the parameter and I solve this issue by assigning a special value to all NA-entries and then have show a modified axis:


I watched the video (from the link you provided) and I don't see that snapping behavior when I run your code.  The content of your question appears to focus on  a different elements (things other than snapping). Can you clarify what it is or isn't plotting that you want to see differently?  I'm not sure why you've stated that the constraint range isn't working, either? What behavior were you expecting?

I hope my edit makes clear what I mean: There is indeed this snapping behaviour in my case. I added my plotly-version too. The constraint range is not working in the sense that in the code I specified .1 and .4 as limits and in the picture there is .18 and .42 as limits (or something similar).
